# Green border around fonts in GIMP

Tags: fonts, gimp, antialiasing

I have a problem in the way text appears in GIMP, I think its related to hinting or anti-aliasing but I have no idea about the cause nor the solution for it.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a workaround is available to this problem. Just turn off the anti-aliasing. But the font look very ugly if we turn off that.

Another Solution is just create a file in

```
sudo gedit /etc/gimp/2.0/fonts.conf
```

Paste the lines

```
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Save and Close the editor.

You can find the details in 
http://smashingweb.info/solved-green-border-around-gimp-text/

Just try this 
Dont know whether it will work or not.

Comment: `~/.gimp-2.8/fonts.conf` works as well

Comment: Yes. In Gimp 2.8 it works perfect.

Comment: After create the conf file, close and re-open GIMP, you have to edit the text to see the green border go away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "anti-aliasing" problem.

Look at the image format, it needs to be set to RGB. It's probably a 256 color palette now. The menu is:

Image » Mode » RGB

Note that at the time you save your image you can convert it back to a paletted image. However, you may again lose quality. Also make sure to keep a .xcf version of the file (Gimp's format) so that way you can do further edits later.

Comment: The color mode is already RGB.. :/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a file with ready text layers. And after adding a fonts.conf file and closing Gimp and reopening the file, green borders around text were still there. I found out that to make text look good, I need to disable and enable the anti-aliasing for each text layer. Hope this helps someone.