# Google Chrome - Rendering Yellow Fonts with Green Border on HDMI Screen

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, fonts, hdmi

## System

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Dual monitors, both Samsung S24D300

  - Left is a HDMI to DVI
  - Right is a VGA cable

## Problem

So using Google Chrome, it seems that one the HDMI to DVI monitor, yellow fonts, are rendered with a Green border, as shown below on the left.

#### Google Chrome Rendering

[image]

However when an image is rendered using the image viewer, the yellow is displayed correctly on the monitor, as shown below.

Video of different backgrounds behind the transparent Google png.
[image]

#### Image Preview Rendering

[image]

I found this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538763/green-border-around-fonts-in-gimp), but am unsure why this happens? anti-aliasing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to disable color management in Ubuntu and restart Chrome to see if there's any difference.  I have similar problem recently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome blue border around images on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061141/chrome-blue-border-around-images-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **@Alvin Liang** I was able to remove the weird green border, by just turning off colour management for the display.

*Settings → Devices → Colour* or *Device Colour Profiles*

[image: dialogue screenshot]

Then restart Chrome for the updated setting to take effect.

Comment: This is definitely a bug, either the auto generated monitor profile has problem or Chrome has some incompatibility with it.